# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@TxtTitle".'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

After I click at the submit button, I got this error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@TxtTitle".'` this error appears next to the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` please could someone help me with that?

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace RegistrationForm5
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=DESKTOP-20J5J59;Initial Catalog=RegistrationWebForm1;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into reg" + "(Title, Name, ID, Email, Mobile, Major, Note)values(@TxtTitle, @TxtName, @TxtID, @TxtEmail, @TxtMobile, @LstMajor, @TxtNote)", con);


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TxtTitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TxtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TxtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TxtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", TxtMobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Major", LstMajor.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", TxtNote.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = "Your request has been submitted successfully";

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SqlCommand references `@TxtTitle`, but the parameter is added as `@Title` instead (_i.e._ you forgot the leading `Txt`).  Similar mismatch on all the rest of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with `cmd` variable you added parameter @Title with the correct one is @TxtTitle, i'm seeing that the others aren't ok the final code might be something like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into reg" + "(Title, Name, ID, Email, Mobile, Major, Note)values(@TxtTitle, @TxtName, @TxtID, @TxtEmail, @TxtMobile, @LstMajor, @TxtNote)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtTitle", TxtTitle.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtName", TxtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtID", TxtID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtEmail", TxtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtMobile", TxtMobile.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LstMajor", LstMajor.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtNote", TxtNote.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Label1.Text = "Your request has been submitted successfully";

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: After I did that the validations not appear in the form, and I can submit even if something is missing or wrong format, do you know why?

Comment: @Mariam I suggest that you post another question for that. But as I recall, there's a page-level method called something like `this.Validate()` that causes all your validations to be checked.  You then check the property `this.IsValid`, and run your code _only if the value is true_.

Comment: @Mariam You can look here for an example:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.validate?view=netframework-4.8